# Is a sound device necessary for an audio streaming server?

Tags: linux, audio, server, streaming, icecast

My project is to stream audio online with my PC as the server.
I have a HP Proliant ML110 G7 server PC, which does not have any integrated sound device in motherboard, nor any kind of sound device.
I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 in my PC, and I cannot configure IceCast and Ices2/Darkice properly, but I could do it following the same instructions in another laptop with same os same version, which has an integrated sound device.

Is an integrated sound device needed to make an audio streaming server?

Thank you.

Comment: Soundcard is not required to run Icecast/Ices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icecast itself just passes data on through.  It requires no sound device at all.

Your source client, such as IceS, can be used to read audio from a sound device or just to read audio from files.  If you have no sound device, you'll need to use some other audio source of course.